# Using Page Title with Node Tags

Tags: nodes, 7

I'm using the following modules

- Meta Tags
- Page Title

I need to be able to make the sites title work like this:

Use the title set in Meta Tags for each Node first of all, if this isn't set then default to the Page Title module.

If this isn't set, just use the pages title.

How do I set a precedence for the titles?  Do I have to hook into html_head_alter?

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked the [auto nodetitle module](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) with the token Module. Then you can create the node Titles with tokens.
Check also the [Automatic Entity Label](http://drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) i think its better for your Usecase

Answer (score -1):

Er, just checking, think I was actually referring to the master metatags settings page when using the word 'global' there.

Whilst debugging I changed my settings on the node itself, but also in admin/config/search/metatags
I thought I would need to set the rule 'globally' in admin/config/search/metatags, as this is where the content types get their configuration settings form.
Then i assumed, this could be overridden on a per node basis by setting the page title on the node itself.

I've added some attachments to confirm my settings.

Comment: Wait, what?  What attachments?  Referring to what?  I'm confused. :P